# emacs interface to ubuntu package management (apt, dpkg)

Tags: package, linux, libraries, ubuntu

Is there an emacs library for managing packages on Ubuntu,
ie an emacs based alternative to `synaptic` and `aptitude`?
Presumably this would be an elisp wrapper around `apt`, `dpkg` and friends
and look something like the `packages` interface ELPA.

Answer (score 1):

A search for "emacs apt wrapper" revealed https://github.com/xwl/ga, "generic apt(from Debian GNU/Linux) like wrapper over various package management tools". Another result was https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForDebian, which has even more options.